# in the python imgaug library, when applying affine transformations to image, how do I set cval to RGB?

Tags: python, data-augmentation

from the documentation, the cval parameter is described as follows:

The constant value used to fill up pixels in the result image that didn’t exist in the input image (e.g. when translating to the left, some new pixels are created at the right).

I'm trying to set it's value to RGB (specifically green).

```
seq = iaa.Sequential([iaa.Affine(rotate=30,cval=255)])
seq_det = seq.to_deterministic()
new_image = seq_det.augment_image(image)

f, axs = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(20,6))
axs[0].imshow(image)
axs[1].imshow(new_image)
plt.show()
```

[here is an example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPzTe.png)
I want to set the white background in the r.h.s picture to green